# Python - Can't add more than 1 score to a list

Tags: python, list, append

Sorry if I get this wrong, this is my first post.

I wrote a program to keep a LIST of cricketers and their scores and adds new scores to their tally which works fine but when I add a new batsman, I can't add more than one score. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please I have been at this for two days now. Here is the code: -

```
import pickle
scores = [["Moe", 100], ["Curly", 50], ["Larry", 0]]

#setup the save function same as usual
def save_scores():
    file = open("pickle.dat", "wb")
    pickle.dump(scores, file)
    file.close()
    print('Scores Saved')
    print()

#setup the load same as yours    
def load_scores():
    file = open("pickle.dat", "rb")
    scores = pickle.load(file)
    file.close()
    print(scores)
    print()

#print the scores to the screen
def print_scores():
    for i in range(0,len(scores)):
        print(scores[i])
    print()

#add a score to the list        
def add_score():
    #first setup a flag like in a bubble sort. This will show if we find a name
    flag = False
    a = ''
    #ask for the name and the new score
    name = input("Enter your name: ")
    score = int(input("Enter your score: "))
    #now count through the list of names
    for i in range (0,len(scores)):
        #take out each name and store it in var a
        a = (scores[i][0])
        #strip the space off the end. Unfortunately, when Python stores names
        #in a list it adds spaces to the end of them. The only way to strip them
        #off is to put them in a variable first, hence a
        a.replace(' ','')
        #now we set the flag if we find the name we just typed in
        if a == name:
            #and add the score to the name in the list
            scores[i].append(score)
            flag = True
    #if we get to here and the flag is still false then the name doesn't exist
    #in the list so we add the name and the score to the list
    if flag == False:
        arr = (name,score)
        scores.append(arr)

def print_menu():
    print('1. Print Scores')
    print('2. Add a Score')
    print('3. Load Scores')
    print('4. Save Scores')
    print('5. Quit')
    print()

menu_choice = 0
print_menu()
while True:
    menu_choice = int(input("Type in a number (1-5): "))
    if menu_choice == 1:
        print_scores()
    if menu_choice == 2:
        add_score()
    if menu_choice == 3:
        print_scores()
    if menu_choice == 4:
        save_scores()
    if menu_choice == 5:
        print ("Goodbye")
        break
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can't add more than one score"?

Comment: Please add some sample inputs and show their outputs. Your question is very confusing

Comment: Sorry, if I select option 2 and add the name Bert and give him a score, it saves it to the list but if I then try to add another score for Bert it won't work

Comment: Type in a number (1-5): 2
    Enter your name: Bert
    Enter your score: 50
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Mr Atkinson\Documents\Python\test.py", line 69, in <module>
    add_score()
  File "C:\Users\Mr Atkinson\Documents\Python\test.py", line 45, in add_score
    scores[i].append(score)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @MikeAtkinson That's cause your are using a Tuple instead of a list

Comment: how do I add a player as part of the list so that I can use it in the same way as the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
arr = (name,score)
```

with:

```
arr = [name,score]
```

The thing is you are using a `tuple` when a new player is added. But `tuples` are **immutable** in python you cannot modify them. That is the reason you are unable to append further scores to a new player. Replacing `tuple` with a `list` will fix the issue as `lists` are **mutable**.

Comment: Man that's awesome, thank you sincerely, I have been trying for hours

Comment: OK got it, you were really fast and excellent, thank you again